langchain with_structured_output Parsing a dictionary of lists of custom classes
I am trying to use Langchain to Extract Structured Output from Unstructured Texts with LLM Tool-Calling.
I have a code that works:
  import os
  from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
  from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

  model = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-4o-mini-2024-07-18", temperature=0.0)

  class A(BaseModel):
    a_1: str
    a_2: str
    r: str

  class B(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b_1: str
    b_2: str
    r: str
  
  class C(BaseModel):
    ccc:List[A]
    ppp: List[B]

  structured_llm = model.with_structured_output(C)

  response = structured_llm.invoke(prompt)

I want to get "a" as a key in ppp , but code (using Dict) below fails:
  import os
  from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
  from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

  model = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-4o-mini-2024-07-18", temperature=0.0)

  class A(BaseModel):
    a_1: str
    a_2: str
    r: str

  class B(BaseModel):
    b_1: str
    b_2: str
    r: str
  
  class C(BaseModel):
    ccc:List[A]
    ppp: Dict[str, List[B]]


  structured_llm = model.with_structured_output(C)

  response = structured_llm.invoke(prompt)


Error :
ValidationError: 1 validation error for C
ppp
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'ccc': [{'a_1': 'Price',...tant to Battery Life'}]}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.9/v/missing

Any clue how to format it as a Dict?
